# Javascript - String to Coordinates Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm new to Javascript and i'm having some issues converting a string to an array of coordinates values .

This is my string (Temporary - the string might have more/less coordinates) :

```
var str = "12:13.94:13:14.9:";
```

each coordinate are separated by a ":" , where

```
str[0] = x1;
str[1] = y1;
str[2] = x2;
str[3] = y2;
.................
```

I want it to return a 2D array of coordinates as :

```
var cArray = [[12,13.94],[13,14.9].........];
```

Is there any way to do this ?

I tried :

```
var cString = coorStr.split(":");
```

But it just returns an array of string,

This is what i have so far : https://jsfiddle.net/mLskwxyj/

Comment: `var cArray = [cString.slice(0, 2), cString.slice(2, 4)]`? There is no single function to do what you want.

Comment: `JSON.parse("["+"12:13.94:13:14.9:".replace(/([\d\.]+):([\d\.]+)/g,"[$1,$2]").replace(":",",").slice(0,-1)+"]")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492385/how-to-convert-simple-array-into-two-dimensional-arraymatrix-in-javascript-or

Answer (score 3):

[tadman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638796/1391671) gives a way to parse your string into an array of numbers:

```
var str = '12:13,94:13:14,9';
var num = str.split(':').map(Number);
```

For a generic way to split this array into `[x, y]` pairs, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31355881/1391671) provides a terse solution. I've slightly modified it below (to remove the Lodash dependency):

```
var coords = num.reduce(function (r, v, i, a) {
  // on every even element, grab a pair of numbers and 
  // add to the result
  if (i % 2 === 0)
    r.push(a.slice(i, i + 2));

  return r;
}, []);
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FH9EbXMeffZ86FsJM0nj?p=preview) is a working example. Note that a `for` loop with a pre-allocated result array will be more performant. I just wanted to provide a way to do it in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit clunky but arranges them as you want:

```
var str = "12:13,94:13:14,9:";

var split = str.replace(/,/g, '.').split(':').map(Number);

var result = [
  [ split[0], split[1] ],
  [ split[2], split[3] ],
];

console.log(result);
// [ [ 12, 13.94 ], [ 13, 14.9 ] ]
```

Accounts for the European style use of `,` in numbers.

**Update**: Added `.map(Number)` as suggested.

Comment: you might want to add a `.map(Number)`

Comment: Yeah, did it a more hack way, but fixed now. Great call. Thanks!

Comment: @tadman - will this work in a for loop in the event where the string has more coordinates

Comment: @Jimmy: Of course not. If you need a loop, use a loop instead of the array literal. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/1048572) (and those linked from there) for generic solutions of all kinds.

Comment: Is there an example for the for loop code . I'm trying in js.do but getting error in my forloop  for(int i = 0 ; i<split.length ; i++)
{

}

Comment: "Getting an error" is the least helpful thing you can say. Try and be specific about the nature of the error, such as the actual text you're getting.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566667/split-javascript-array-in-chunks-using-underscore-js) for inspiration.